# Upgrade to Java 8 on a Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS machine

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I currently have installed 1.7.0_121 for my user account and I don't have sudo privileges. I would like to update from my terminal to Java 8. I have seen this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/521145/how-to-install-oracle-java-on-ubuntu-14-04) where it is mentioned to issue the commands

```
   sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

however, these don't work for me (apt-add-repository fails). How should I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: Get the Server jre which is a jdk in disguise and extract it to your home

Comment: This is not directly programming-related and is most probably a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Yes, please move the question to another site like @Turing85 suggest or to https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *update* to Java 8, but you can install Java 8 in parallel to the already installed Java version.

For that, just go to the [Oracle Java Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) page and download the .tar.gz variant for your platform. Then you can just extract it somewhere in your home folder.

Finally you can add the *bin* folder within the extracted package to your path to execute the new Java version from the commandline.

The downside of this method is, that you cannot change the java version for system services! (You would need sudo privileges or root access for that.)

Maybe also other services/daemons/servers you start on your own, maybe you have to point them to your newly installed Java version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't do that without sudo priviliges. Ask your system administrator to do this for you.

Comment: @Makoto *for my user account and I don't have sudo privileges.*

Comment: @Makoto They state in the question that they don't have sudo priviliges. Please read the question carefully next time.